# How do I implement CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate using ShellRenderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Previously I was able to use TabbedRenderer to stylize the tabbed bar More menu page by implementing CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate as so...

```
public class ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        { 
            MoreNavigationController.Delegate = new CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm now using Shell navigation instead, and so how can I assign/implement this class using ShellRenderer (since there is no OnElementChanged override)?

My More menu styling class

```
internal class CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate : UINavigationControllerDelegate
    {
        public override void WillShowViewController(UINavigationController navigationController, UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
        {
            viewController.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;

            UILabel titleLabel = new UILabel();

            if (viewController.NavigationItem.Title != "More")
            {
                titleLabel.Text = viewController.NavigationItem.Title;
            }
            else
            {
                titleLabel.Text = "More";
            }

            titleLabel.TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark ? UIColor.White : UIColor.Black;
            viewController.NavigationItem.TitleView = titleLabel;

            viewController.View.BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark ? ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.iOSDarkPageBackgroundColor : ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.iOSLightPageBackgroundColor;
            viewController.View.TintColor = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark ? UIColor.White : UIColor.Black;

            if (viewController.View is UITableView tableView)
            {
                tableView.SeparatorColor = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark ? UIColor.White : UIColor.Black;
                foreach (var cell in tableView.VisibleCells)
                {
                    cell.BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark ? ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.iOSDarkPageBackgroundColor : ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.iOSLightPageBackgroundColor;
                    cell.TextLabel.TextColor = cell.TintColor = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark ? UIColor.White : UIColor.Black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `override` the **required methods** to perform the required customization via a subclass of the `ShellRenderer` class to customize the Tabbar appearance.

For example,in iOS, if you want to set the text of the more menu of the Shell application.

**Code snippet:**

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xaminals.AppShell), typeof(Xaminals.iOS.MyShellRenderer))]
namespace Xaminals.iOS
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new TabBarAppearance();
        }
    }

    public class TabBarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
        {
        }

        public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
           //set tabbar appearance
        }

    
        public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
        {
            UITabBar tb = controller.MoreNavigationController.TabBarController.TabBar;
            if (tb.Subviews.Length > 4)
            {
                UIView tbb = tb.Subviews[4];
                UILabel label = (UILabel)tbb.Subviews[1];
                label.Text = "CustomTab";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, please refer to our MS [official docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers)

Comment: So how can my existing CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate class be assigned in ShellRenderer (to stylize the More menu colors)?  It doesn't appear there is a way to access the MoreNavigationController property (which was available using TabbedRenderer).

Comment: Updated post above to show my CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate class previously used to stylize the More menu page

Comment: I've updated my answer.Feel free to check it.Thanks!